# Adding user input for arrayList.set

Tags: java, arrays

I've been working on the following assignment:
 This program should create an ArrayList called Book List. The program 
should display a menu to allow the user to choose from the following options:

> Enter 1 to add a book to the list:
>
> Enter 2 to edit a book to the list:
>
> Enter 3 to remove a book from the list:
>
> Enter 4 to display the list of books:
>
> Enter 5 to quit:

The program should use a case/switch statement and switch on the users choice. The program should continue until the user enters 5 to quit.

1. Case 1 should use BookList.add to add books to the ArrayList.
2. Case 2 should use BookList.set to edit books to the ArrayList.
3. Case 3 should use BookList.remove to remove a name from the list (Ask the user to enter the index number of the book to delete from ArrayList).
4. Case 4 should use a for loop to display all books in the ArrayList
   along with their index number.

(Sample output) Your output should look similar to:

> **********The Book List*********
>
> Index: 0 Name: Stranger in a Strange Land
>
> Index: 1 Name: PHP and MySQL
>
> Index: 2 Name: HTML & CSS
>
> Index: 3 Name: Love Story
>
> Index: 4 Name: The Day the Earth Stood Still

I am having trouble with ArrayList.set. I can not figure out how to take user input (the index number and the corrected book title) to update the array list.  That's not the end of my issues with this program, but any help on ArrayList.set would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BookList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Create array
        ArrayList<String> bookList = new ArrayList<String>();

        //Add a few books to the array bookList
        bookList.add("A Game of Thrones");
        bookList.add("A Clash of Kings");
        bookList.add("A Storm of Swords");
        bookList.add("A Feast for Crows");
        bookList.add("A Dance with Dragons");

        //Display the items in bookList array and their indices.
        System.out.println("******** The Book List ********");
        for (int index = 0; index < bookList.size(); index++)
        {System.out.println("Index:  " + index + "    Name: " + bookList.get(index));}
        System.out.print("\n");


        //declaring variables
        int menuID = 0;
        int changeIndex = 0;
        int delIndex = 0;
        String addTitle = "";
        String corrTitle = "";


        //Menu
        System.out.println("Enter 1 to add a book to the list");
        System.out.println("Enter 2 to edit a book in the list");
        System.out.println("Enter 3 to remove a book from the list");
        System.out.println("Enter 4 display the list of books");
        System.out.println("Enter 5 to quit");
        System.out.println("Enter a menu number (1-4 or 5 to Exit): ");
        menuID = input.nextInt();

        while (menuID != 0)
        {

            if (menuID >=1 && menuID <= 4)
            {
                switch (menuID)
                {
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("Enter the book to add: ");
                        addTitle = keyboard.nextLine();
                        bookList.add(addTitle);

                        System.out.print("\n");
                        System.out.println("******** The Book List ********");
                        for (int index = 0; index < bookList.size(); index++)
                        {System.out.println("Index:  " + index + "    Name: " + bookList.get(index));}
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("Enter index number of the book to change: ");
                        changeIndex = keyboard.nextInt();

                        System.out.println("Enter the corrected book name: ");
                        corrTitle = keyboard.nextLine();

                        bookList.set(changeIndex, corrTitle);

                        System.out.println("******** The Book List ********");
                        for (int index = 0; index < bookList.size(); index++)
                        {System.out.println("Index:  " + index + "    Name: " + bookList.get(index));}
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        System.out.println("Enter index number of the book to remove: ");
                        delIndex = keyboard.nextInt();
                        bookList.remove(delIndex);

                        System.out.println("******** The Book List ********");
                        for (int index = 0; index < bookList.size(); index++)
                        {System.out.println("Index:  " + index + "    Name: " + bookList.get(index));}
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        System.out.println("******** The Book List ********");
                        for (int index = 0; index < bookList.size(); index++)
                        {System.out.println("Index:  " + index + "    Name: " + bookList.get(index));}
                        break;

                    case 5:
                        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                        break;
                }}
            else if (menuID >=1 && menuID <= 4)
                System.out.println("You must enter a number 1-5:");
            System.out.println("Enter a menu number (1-4 or 5 to Exit): ");
            menuID = input.nextInt();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read: [How to create a **Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Don't just dump the entire code on us.

Comment: Have you learned about methods yet? If so, you should create a method, e.g. named `listBooks()`, so you don't have to repeat the logic for printing the list of books 4 times.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using only one `Scanner` object with the same source, unless you had a really complicated way to traverse the input, which probably isn't the case here. So your code should look something like this:

```
// Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
// ...
menuID = input.nextInt();

while (menuID != 0)
{
    if (menuID >=1 && menuID <= 4)
    {
        switch (menuID)
        {
            case 1:
                // ...
                addTitle = input.nextLine();
// ...
```

Now, there's another issue because you're calling `Scanner.nextInt`, which gets you the next integer, but won't consume the rest of the line after taking the integer, so when you call `Scanner.nextLine` it will get you the rest of that previous line instead of the new line you're expecting. To fix that, you could call a dummy `Scanner.nextLine` after each `Scanner.nextInt`, like this:

```
menuID = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine(); // Consumes the rest of the line
```

Or you could get the whole line every time and parse the integer it contains, using `Integer.parseInt`, like this:

```
menuID = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
```

[Here's the working code](https://tio.run/##7VdLU9swEL7nV2xzYJxSAuFxaALMUKAMU9pLuHTaHhR7kwhsKZXkBJrht9OVLTmBOCEptNPpVBfH2t1P@/h2rVyxIduQAxRX0fXb@3ueDKQycEW79dTwuH6kFLu94Nq0KjOydsiEQNWqVMKYaQ3vpLy2qjCuVAZpJ@YhaMMMPYaSR5AwLoK2UVz0vnwDpnq6ZjWBlkMCLgapgQMQOPJ7QftWG0zqXNRaufLm5rFCZpAgyLdsq/ByP8c/hI73JQebUQg8msU7iiJg0CU9a6bBSDB9h18gOW3/WmdRFFSP4IwlCLILl30lBeoq4ZYrHlOO@lbzA52/QK9tpEqsXnskVbRA8T0yiq8rFRwrOVqgeMJEiDDipg8nivWkyHSL6E@4HsQUqA2ZU6o1lWGSvzwJTERWzm2JIh6irjtzVx2ZmvqAEmtiEVRfu0U5wYwUkCH57Ymj1veAjCwo3lCptlru5/4kCM1/IFUrF6yv15ztuOzkc6vTBKjCugNap9@0PlGVmtl2gdtDE2Q6tVrrbk40QfWryHLliBchMd3yB4b0YJ0YdSaxMSQo0vOTLIhiL@wz0cPzIrpCEGH8aDfnJVDJLrmJkQTV6gNJKJWaFnmfPtK5UJlXi1NhqK8altIsY7mN3xM8pjz4asw33rbqGHHjrYkey1vvWGuFiRyit@8qmayAsAvRFEOtje2OrFOfNt6zx39P@RLnsKyEINKkQ29BY2MXpAM4veGmRvxxGEWpz8mwh6o@YEpTmS2haIDVBd6YCy6Itr7PRn1OhQuc4Suqes7jsW9DokW3kB8eNGBtzR@zfwC7tUJt7J7FxvTS1ORh3@PUSnXGpbsh0wiNZqlscdpsUTypiGKTLJWtKXo/TtV8owfzzCNMJtjTzvo2XiW4pYdY2XrOYCut2e8YdiWJpu/q9Zy8ZgTZ/hWC5L65tqLOnSZMPiAXc@bhEF265VZnsZ2wGBqMcvdEnsZFnk2N5Fk6P81nTVWZiu7NBHDVIJ7D1hcm69/C1Z2X5mr@EVvMiKnv@jJEfZIh@ZmBh/2TtPhnh9hu838On5vDvdVyeCZl1LnFV4uS5c4sE93N8RRjcmXJe9Mybn6WKSQpFRfdhdANgsbGXnPV@8Oqd8qytfo9cyZzS@6OZ81nle7u77crW5VLpD/DWz8B) using the second option (which I find better for this case)

As a side note, you're asking the user to exit with `5`, but your `while` depends continues as long as the `menuID` is not `0`